# Problem installing any distro of linux, AMD problem?

Tags: boot, bios

I've tried Ubuntu, Fedora, CentOS, USB and DVD ISO. But every time I have several problems, for example:

1. kernel panic attempted to kill the idle task
2. kernel panic not syncing
3. AMD-Vi completion-wait loop timed out

Any suggestion?

Comment: Rather than the different distros, details on the software stacks on each provide far more detail that listing names such as fedora/ubuntu/centos (though usually CentOS means an old software stack so it's a little more unique, but without release info how old is not known).  Were you trying different ages? anything modern?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04, fedora 1.6, centOS 8.1 those are the ones I've tried

Comment: Check for download errors of the Ubuntu ISO by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu  If checksum validates OK, make a LiveUSB following these instructions on another Linux PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows or on a Mac https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos  Also, what is make and model part number of the PC; get model part number from serial number sticker; other 'model' names are marketing buzzwords

Comment: Your fedora is not a valid release, early Fedora release were called Fedore Core, however FC1 a 2003 release so is prehistoric. Though if you meant Fedora 16 - that's still very old being from 2011 reaching EOL in 2012. CentOS 8 used a kernel & stack ~equivalent to a Ubuntu of 2018.  On Ubuntu 20.04 you haven't ruled out user errors (did you verify the ISO?  did you get a clean verify of your install media?  if you can't on that box use another box for the purpose as you're wasting your time until you've completed earlier tests)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entered the BIOS and switched off `amd_iommu`.